# Why does my Wireless connection block my internet traffic?

Tags: networking, wireless, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I am on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 and experincing a strange "bug".

When i have wireless activated and connect my coble bound network - it looks like everything is fine (in the menu bar i see a connection on cable and one for wireless) - but I dont have Internet at all.

When I deactivate my wireless connection - everything works again...
...so I can live with this dirty workaround - but this wasn't occuring when I used older Ubuntus (but there I was on the standard unity based Release plan)

My Hardware is a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro http://www.linlap.com/lenovo_ideapad_yoga_2_pro

here some more infos (i masked mac adresses and ipv6):
ifconfig with wireless connection without connected rj45:

route -n

```
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

$ ifconfig

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:1323913 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:737593 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:1906094750 (1.9 GB)  TX-Bytes:77943741 (77.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:6296 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:6296 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
      RX-Bytes:609707 (609.7 KB)  TX-Bytes:609707 (609.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet Adresse:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
      RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet Adresse:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: 0000::0000:0000:0000:0000/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:177 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:224 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:59623 (59.6 KB)  TX-Bytes:69647 (69.6 KB)
```

Activated WLAN without RJ45:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:1323913 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:737593 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:1906094750 (1.9 GB)  TX-Bytes:77943741 (77.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:6296 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:6296 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
      RX-Bytes:609707 (609.7 KB)  TX-Bytes:609707 (609.7 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet Adresse:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
      RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet Adresse:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: 0000::0000:0000:0000:0000/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:177 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:224 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:59623 (59.6 KB)  TX-Bytes:69647 (69.6 KB)
```

connected rj45 with activated wireless:

$ route -n

```
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    400    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

$ ifconfig

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet Adresse:192.168.1.156  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: 0000::0000:0000:0000:000/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:1323958 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:737638 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:1906104358 (1.9 GB)  TX-Bytes:77951597 (77.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:6453 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:6453 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
      RX-Bytes:624567 (624.5 KB)  TX-Bytes:624567 (624.5 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet Adresse:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
      RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:00:00:00:00:00  
      inet Adresse:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: 0000::0000:0000:0000:0000/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:557 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:551 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
      RX-Bytes:188727 (188.7 KB)  TX-Bytes:154595 (154.5 KB)
```

in the latest status no ping is going thorugh:

```
ping www.heise.de
PING www.heise.de (193.99.144.85) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- www.heise.de ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4032ms
```

Comment: In both cases wlan0 is connected. You better show `route -n` than `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use two network interfaces at the same time without special routing setup, since the system will not know were to send packets to reach to the Internet.

If you connect to your wired network with activated wireless connection, system tries to connect through wireless network, if it is connected to some access point.

Just check if you are connected somewhere.

It is not related to Ubuntu versions or hardware. Maybe you need to clean up your wireless connections, not to automatically connect everywhere.

Comment: Observation: In my computer, Network Manager defaults the Ethernet as the default route.  I've had to change this in the past, manually, via the command line, by forcing the default route to be through the wifi card instead of ethernet, and other weirdness.  (However your answer *is* correct, you'd have to manually change the default route in these cases)

Comment: Well - I know that - and before I used ubuntu gnome (which doesn't need to be realted to the problem, its just a time mark for myself) the classical "plug rj45 - and it will get used" unplug rj45 and wireless will be used" just doesn't work anymore... - if I have an activated wireless connection and I plug into my rj45 - I have no network at all - until I deactivate wireless...

Comment: @Mr.Gosh This means that default route is through wireless.

Comment: But that would not explain why my connectivity drops if i connect rj45